# Does Alto's Adventure/Odyssey allow "reviving" indefinitely in the Android version (free-to-play)?

Tags: android, altos-adventure, altos-odyssey

The porting company [Noodlecake](https://noodlecake.com/about/) changed to the free-to-play model for the Android version. [On Android both games allow reviving fallen Alto](https://youtu.be/lfefi0vbeQM?t=69) (or any other character) by watching an add or by using 1500 coins (there's an IAP to buy more). Is there any hard limit?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Watching ads boost the company's income, so they'll keep doing that whenever you fall. Unless your wifi-connection is bad or you don't have enough money, you can keep reviving Alto(or any other character).

Comment: There's some limitation at place, the game doesn't seem to allow continuing (the option isn't shown) at least when falling again within the next 30 seconds or so.